# How to filter(blur) image in Flutter using Image.asset?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was generally using `AssetImage` and its `colorFilter` property to filter my image in different ways:

```
image: DecorationImage(
    image: AssetImage("assets/images/1.jpg"), 
    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey[800], BlendMode.modulate),
    fit: BoxFit.cover),
    color: Colors.teal[900],
)
```

I am using `SliverAppBar` right now and its `flexibleSpace` field takes `FlexibleSpaceBar` and `FlexibleSpaceBar` in turn takes a `Widget`. Here I can give `Image.asset` but as I cannot filter, make blur that image. Is there any way to filter child of `Image.asset` ?

- `FlexibleSpaceBar`'s `background` takes only `Widget` so I can not give it `AssetImage`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/1.jpg"),
        colorFilter:
            ColorFilter.mode(Colors.grey[800], BlendMode.modulate),
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
    color: Colors.teal[900],
  ),
  child: ClipRect(
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```